# jQuery's .ajax is losing data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okay I'm fiddling around with this for hours and getting frustrated.
I want to build an application form with ajax. I pass an associative array with huge nested arrays in it:

```
[
    "foo": x,
    "bar": y,
     // ...
]
```

[Here](http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/blackrock/smasher?fields=feed,guild,items,progression,stats,talents) is an example what `x or y` can look like (it's way too huge to post it here). It's basically just an object with nested arrays in it:

```
{
    lastModified: 1243245656
    some: x
    other: y
    keys: z
    feed: [ ... ]
    items: [ ... ]
    // ...
}
```

So my associative array `added_toons` would like this:

```
[
    "foo": {
        lastModified: 1243245656
        some: x
        other: y
        keys: z
        feed: [ ... ]
        items: [ ... ]
        // ...
    },
    "bar": {
        lastModified: 1243245656
        some: x
        other: y
        keys: z
        feed: [ ... ]
        items: [ ... ]
        // ...
    },
    // ..
]
```

Here comes the problem: When I evaluate my array right before I pass it with ajax everything is fine. As soon as I receive it in my php backend there are missing arrays within each `toon`. `items` and `feed` for example.
I really have no idea what is happening.

So I'm asking for some help to troubleshoot this. AFAIK it shouldn't be a problem with escaping since jQuery already does this for me.

---

My JS code

```
    console.info(added_toons); // everything is fine here
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'action': 'submit',
             // ...
            'toons': added_toons
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            // ...
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            // ..
        }
    });
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
if ($_POST['action'] == 'submit') {
    // when I here evaluate $_POST it contains `toons` 
    // but each `toon` is missing keys
}
```

Comment: what happens when u use JSOn.stringify?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way to set  `JSON.stringify` for your `added_toons`

```
data: {
        'action': 'submit',
         //stringify is important to send array of objects
        'toons': JSON.stringify(added_toons) 
      },
```

See about `JSON.stringify()` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Oh my gosh.. yeah this works, just decode it in PHP again.. Thank you

Comment: @Brettetete no prob :)

Comment: Hold on... this works very infrequent. One try it works next it fails. Same data.. huh

Comment: Yep... `json_last_error()` says it's an `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. `json_last_error_msg()` => `quoted object property name expected`. Well but as far as I can see they are.